# Issue with One to One Mapping in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am just started with hibernate 4 (annotations), I have following three model Classes with One to One and One to Many Relationship.`

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "USERS",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"EMAIL_ID"})})
public class UserBasicInfo implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="userId")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;
    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="userBasicInfo",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserDeviceInfo> userDeviceInfo;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="userBasicInfo",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserAdvancedInfo userAdvancedInfo;

///////// Getter setters 
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS_ADVANCED_DETAILS")
public class UserAdvancedInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ADVANCED_INFO_ID")
    private Integer advancedInfoId;
    @Column(name="GENDER")
    private Gender gender;
    @Column(name="UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT")
    private UnitOfMeasurement unitOfMeasurement;
    @Column(name="HEIGHT")
    private Double height;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId",  insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = true)
    private UserBasicInfo userBasicInfo;

    ////////////////////////  Getter and Setter ////////////////////////
}
```

On the basis of above model classes I have two different REST APIs.
In the first API, only basic info will inserted and that is working fine.

But in the second API I have to update On UserAdvancedInfo on the basis of primary key of UserBasicInfo.
I have used update, merge, saveOrUpdate, but instead of updating data these all methods inserting a new row every time.
Kindly help me out.

Thanks,

Comment: your first service is only inserting basic information, so there will be no rows inserted in the UserAdvancedInfo. right?

Comment: Yes! Correct @YogeshHShenoy

Comment: so when you use the second service UserAdvanceInfo will have a new row and the UserBasicInfo table the new id of UserAdvanceInfo will be updated. And your problem is that there is a new entry in UserBasicInfo table? is it?

Comment: No, The problem is there is a new entry in UserAdvanceInfo table.

Comment: I am not updating the id of UserAdvanceInfo  in UserBasicInfo.

Comment: To update detail from UserAdvanceInfo, before calling session.update() method you need to make sure you get the data you want to update using session.find() or session.get().  If you simply create new object and assign value it will be treated as new row.

Comment: Add the code with update `UserAdvancedInfo`, please.

Comment: I have used Inheritance (Table Per subClass Hierarchy ), and that is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

To update the entity, you should need to set primary key to UserAdvancedInfo object and set UserBasicInfo object with there primary key to UserAdvancedInfo object :

```html
UserAdvancedInfo info = new UserAdvancedInfo();
UserBasicInfo userInfo =new UserBasicInfo();
info.setUserBasicInfo(userInfo);
```

Hibernate checks for primary key for updation.